# String operations 6 digit number replace units and tens digits with dynamci numbers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I got a requirement like,its a 6-digit number
first loop has to print like below,

```
string str="000000";
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
int fundCount=0,reportCount=0;
For(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
   sb.Append(str+",");
}
```

OutPut should look like below:

```
000000
000011
000012
000013
000014  //Here all 1's are fundCount,1,2,--9 are report count
000015
000016
000017
000018
000019
```

second loop should print like,

```
000021
000022
000023
000024 //Here all 2's are fundCount,1,2,--9 are report count
000025
000026
000027
000028
000029
```

I need to print such format till fundcount reaches 100 and 6-digit number remains as a 6-Digit,it shouldnot modify to 7-digit number when fundcount reaches 10(i mean 2-digts or 3-digits).Please helpme out of this.

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't understand right your request but why couldn't you use string.Format? In this case it will look like this:

string.Format("{0:000000}", i);

where i is your number.